# Writing and reading of a File in a Perl program

Tags: perl, file-handling

I have an original file **A.txt**.
I write to **A_Copy.txt**.
I want to know if I can read **A_Copy.txt** before closing and after closing it in the same program?
I want to modify **A_Copy.txt** using  `Tie::File` in the same program.

A -> A_Copy.txt

Read A_Copy.txt before closing

Read A_Copy.txt after closing

Modify A_Copy.txt

Comment: If you want to know whether the file is readable or not.. Use `-r` with your `file`.. If you want to do anything else.. Show us some code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using copy should be enough to be sure that the old file is readable, and the new file is writable and readable, copy performs very well.
To check if a file is readable the best way is to use -r which uses the system stat call

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Copy;
use Tie::File;

my $i = "A.txt";      # input file
my $o = "A_Copy.txt"; # output file
my @a;                # array to use with tie

copy($i, $o) or die;  

# check that the new file is readable, actually unneeded since copy
# would fail on any error
die unless (-r $o);   

# fill an array with the lines of the new file
tie @a, "Tie::File", $o or die;
# change the first line of the new file
$a[0] = "Hi";
```